# iText 5 define correct position about rectangle

Tags: java, itext, jasper-reports, position, rectangles

I've done a report with JasperSoft Studio.

In this report I've added a placeholder (an image), with a key.

In Java I've done this code to retrieve information about my placeholder:

```
HashMap<String, InfoImmaginePerFirma> hmSign = new HashMap<String, InfoImmaginePerFirma>();
for (int currPage = 0; currPage < populatedReport.getPages().size(); currPage++) {
    for (JRPrintElement currElement : populatedReport.getPages().get(currPage).getElements()) {
        if (currElement.getKey() != null && currElement.getKey().equals("DMIMySignatureImg")) {
            InfoImmaginePerFirma currInfo = new InfoImmaginePerFirma(currElement.getX(), currElement.getY(), currElement.getWidth(), currElement.getHeight(), currPage);
                        hmSign.put("DMIMySignatureImg", currInfo);
        }
    }   
}
```

In my hmSign Hashmap I've added X, Y, Height and Width about my placeholder.

So after other instructions I've added this code to add on my placeholder a rectangle, as follow:

```
InfoImmaginePerFirma info = hmSign.get("DMIMySignatureImg");
float llx = info.getX();
float lly = info.getY() + (info.getHeight() + 62);
float urx = info.getX() + info.getWidth();
float ury = info.getY() + 62;

PdfFormField sig = PdfFormField.createSignature(stamper.getWriter());
sig.setWidget(new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury), null);
sig.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT); 
sig.put(PdfName.DA, new PdfString("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g")); 
sig.setFieldName("Signature1");
```

and so on...

I've added 62 because I've two band in my report (title and detail) and my placeholder is in the second band.

But when I try to print my report the rectangles is more high as y.

So, I've read these information:

retrieved x, y is the upper left corner of my image

to draw a rectangle I need to know the lower left and upper right corners, so I've retrieved my corners as follow:

```
float llx = X of upper left corner (the X is the same)
float lly = Y of upper left corner + height
float urx = X of upper left corner + width
float ury = Y of upper left corner
```

But if I try to manage these position manually I've noticed the correct Y position about lly is

```
float lly = Y of upper left corner - 362
```

But I don't understand it's possible this.

Comment: Why `lly = Y of upper left corner + height`? The *lower* left corner should be *below* the *upper* left corner, so you should *subtract* the `height` instead of *adding* it, shouldn't you?

Comment: @mkl: Hi dear, I suppose the start of report is 0,0, so 0,0 is the left upper corner, if I want to define lower left I must add the height. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: What coordinate values are you writing about in your question, JasperReports coordinates or iText coordinates? iText coordinates are the standard PDF user space coordinates (unless you applied a transformation) for which adding something means going upwards.

Comment: @mkl: I'm using coordinate retrieved from JRPrintElement (contained in Jasper report namespace). Ok, so, if I add I'm going upwards. Thank you very much!